# change column data type text to decimal of column name 'to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, type-conversion

I have table 'abc' and column 'to' with datatype as 'text'. I want to change to 'decimal'.
INPUT:
 `change_column :abc, :to, 'integer USING CAST(to AS integer)'`
and I got following output :

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to"
>
> LINE 1: " ALTER COLUMN "to" TYPE integer USING CAST(to AS
>   inte...

Comment: I think you need to do something like `change_column :abc, :to, :decimal`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did try this also....but not working

Comment: What is not working? Any error message?

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL? In that case, `to` is a reserved word. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html